# Postgresql on external HD

Tags: postgresql

- I have a set of .csv files many times larger than my hard drive which I would like to load into database tables using postgresql.  (I must keep it locally on an external hard drive due to Data Use Agreement restrictions.)
- I would like to tell Postgresql to store the tables I load on the external drive, due to size constraints.
- I think I can do this with `initdb -D '/Volumes/My Book/2020/'`, where `/Volumes/My Book/2020/` is the path to the folder on the external drive.
- I get the error: `FATAL:  data directory "/Volumes/My Book/2020" has invalid permissions 2021-01-23 11:21:58.864 EST [4390] DETAIL:  Permissions should be u=rwx (0700) or u=rwx,g=rx (0750).`
- But `ls -l "/Volumes/My Book/"` returns (among other lines) `drwxrwxrwx@ 1 my_username  staff  1048576 Jan 19 13:29 2020` which looks like the right set of permissions to me.
- I tried `sudo chown my_username "/Volumes/My Book/2020/"`, but I get the same error as before.
- I tried `sudo chmod a+rwx "/Volumes/My Book/2020/"`, and still get the same error.

Can anyone advise me about how to set the permissions correctly?  (Or failing that: maybe I am taking the wrong approach to this problem?)

Thanks!

Comment: How is your external hard drive mounted?

Comment: Probably I don't understand the question well enough...  It is connected via the USB port, but I don't know if that's what you're asking?   diskutil list shows it under the name /dev/disk2.  Does that answer?

Comment: type `mount` and you should see how your external drive is mounted. Is it ro or rw? If it is rw, can you touch a file on the drive?

Comment: I can ```touch``` and it does create a file in the right place.  ```mount``` returns this: ```/dev/disk2s1 on /Volumes/My Book (exfat, local, nodev, nosuid, noowners)```

Comment: "drwxrwxrwx...which looks like the right set of permissions to me."  No, it wants exactly 0700 or 0750, not at least as lenient as that.  So it thinks your directory, at 0777, is too insecure and doesn't want to run in it. Can you manually set them to 0700, or does the disk just ignore that attempt?

Comment: As far as I can tell I am being ignored: ```sudo chmod 750 "/Volumes/My Book/" ``` followed by ```ls -l /Volumes``` returns the same list ```drwxrwxrwx  1 my_username  staff  1048576 Jan  1  1980 My Book```

Comment: OK, so you can't run PostgreSQL there, unless you are willing to hack the PostgreSQL source code and compile it yourself.  Perhaps you could reformat the drive into a filesystem which supports the necessary features.  That would more of a superuser.com question.

Answer (score 2):

I'm the OP.  Thanks for the help from those above.  Here is what I ended up doing to solve this problem.  I think this is all of the steps but something could be missing.  (This is via Mac on Catalina.)  Happy to accept any corrections if I forgot a step.

- Format the external drive AFPS or GUID via diskutility (using the "view all" command).  (This will delete everything on the drive, so you need a backup.)
- After formatting, `sudo chmod -R 0750 "/Volumes/your_external_hd_name/`  from the command line - this will set the correct permissions.
- `initdb -D '/Volumes/your_external_hd_name/database/'`     # creates a "database cluster"
- `pg_ctl -D /Volumes/your_external_hd_name/database/ start`   # seems to run the cluster
- NB: at the above step, if you get an error including the line "Is another postmaster already running on port 5432?", then run `ps -ef | grep postmaster | awk '{print $2}'` on the command line, followed by `kill <pid1> ... <pidN>` for any PIDs which show up.
- `psql postgres`
- `CREATE DATABASE <database_name>;`
- `\l`                                                 # list databases
- `\c <your_database>`                                 # connect to the database
- `\dt`                                                # list tables
- `CREATE DATABASE <name>;`                            # creates w/in the cluster
- `CREATE TABLE <table>;`                              # include some columns
- `\dt`                                                # to check that it was created,  should appear
- If you need to undo/correct: `DROP TABLE <name>;`
- `\copy <table_name> FROM 'path/to/file';`
- `\q` # exit
- `pg_ctl stop -D /Volumes/your_external_hd_name/`  # seems to be important to prevent database from getting damaged, but I have never disconnected w/out it so I am not 100% sure.

Comment: At the step “Is another postmaster already running on port 5432”, if you don’t want to kill any process, you can change the postgresql.conf file (located in the data folder) and change the port to something else like `port=5431`, then you would call psql with the port number argument: `psql -p 5431 <dbname>`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a database on the external disk, you should run `initdb` with a data directory that does not yet exist. Then PostgreSQL qill create it with the right permissions. The data directory should belong to the `postgres` user. What PostgreSQL complains about is that it cannot *reduce* the permissions on the existing data directory to a setting it considers safe.

If you are running a database cluster on an external disk, make sure that the database is safely shut down before removing the disk.

An alternative you should consider is to define *foreign tables* with [`file_fdw`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/file-fdw.html). Then you could access the files directly from within the database without a need to import them. There are of course some limitations: you cannot have indexes on such foreign tables (so you can only have sequential scans), and no data modifications are possible.

Comment: Thanks.  Let me see if I did it correctly.  I tried: ```initdb -D '/Volumes/My Book/database/' ``` where ```database``` is a directory which doesn't yet exist.  The response I got was still a permissions failure: ```FATAL:  data directory "/Volumes/My Book/database" has invalid permissions``` followed by ```DETAIL:  Permissions should be u=rwx (0700) or u=rwx,g=rx (0750)```

Comment: Perhaps you are using a file system that does not understand about permissions?

Comment: Yes I had that comment from another SO post elsewhere today and it might be the problem.  At least the drive doesn't understand permissions - I don't yet know if I can fix it.  I am moving all of the files (4 Tb) and will reformat the drive and try again.  If I can solve the problem, I will post the answer.